# Cannot load pages hosted in a local IIS server

Tags: iis, web-server, iis-7, hosting, web-hosting

I build an aspx webapp in .net4.0. To test it i hosted it using IIS 7.0. Now i can access the webapp on the computer , which i used to host iis, by typing either

> localhost\myapp

or  using its ip

> 192.168.1.2\myapp

But i cannot access it on another computer within in the same network. It says

> server not found

**I checked the firewall . I can load  pages hosted in Apache.**

i'm using win7

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should check your windows firewall and ensure that TCP port 80 is open for your local network.
2. Server not found usualy means browser is not able to resolve name, double check your url, if you are using ip addr. `http://192.168.1.2/myapp` you shouldnt have such issues. Please try that link.
3. If you have both apache and IIS on your PC, check which webserver sitting on which port. You can check listening ports in the resource monitor resmon.exe

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks..i solved it. Windows firewall was blocking iis service...even though it allowed apache httpd service.